# Qt & Kinect: How do I convert BYTE* pBuffer to a QByteArray or const uchar*?

Tags: c++, qt, kinect, qbytearray

I'm currently combining the Qt library with the Kinect API, and attempting to show the video from the sensor in a QImage (being shown by a QLabel).

In my Kinect handling library, the function that receives the data from the video sensor is emitting the data as a BYTE* (pointing to something with RGB32 values).

In another little corner of my program, I have a slot receiving that BYTE* and attempting to update the QImage with the RGB32 data as follows:

```
videoCanvas->loadFromData(reinterpret_cast<const uchar*>(pBuffer), QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

Where pBuffer is passed into the slot by the signal, and is the aforementioned BYTE*.

This is not working for me, and I'm still stuck with a gray box where the image should be. I imagine that the issue is in the casting, because I have researched the data type and apparently QImage::Format_RGB32 is correct.

How should I proceed with this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadFromData` expects the buffer you are passing to have all the necessary information about the image...including its width and height.  So the format should be things like JPEG or PNG, not a `QImage::Format` constant.

In fact, I'm surprised that line compiled as written...because `loadFromData` expects a char* for it's specification of the "format", and you're passing an integer:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#Format-enum

If what you have is a raw byte array of data, and know the width and height from some other source, you probably want to use the appropriate QImage constructor for that:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-5

*That's* where you use the `QImage::Format` values...